# Deploying .NET Core/Docker to Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine From Visual Studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, kubernetes, .net-core, google-kubernetes-engine

I can't seem to deploy from VS 2017 to Google Cloud Kubernetes engine using the Google Cloud Tools extension for VS.

The deploy progress gets to about 75% and then hangs for hours and hours with no error.

When trying to manually create a dotnet project using Cloud Shell, I get an error message saying it couldn't restore the dotnet packages. Running the dotnet restore command is not successful but does not give an error message.

Even a starting point to where I could debug this would be great.

Comment: You may check the "Deploying on Kubernetes Engine" sub-chapter of the [Visual Studio Deployment Wizard](https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/deployment-wizard) online document. 
There are 4 steps involved: 
1) Open the deployment wizard by clicking Tools > Google Cloud Tools > Publish [PROJECT-NAME] to Google Cloud
2) Select Container Engine
3) Select a cluster for deployment, enter your app's deployment name, version and the number of replicas.
4)Click Publish

Comment: Thanks George! I followed these steps and it just hangs at 75% completion. That link is one of those that I've been using :(

Comment: There are other ways to deploy a .net app to GCP, as described in the [4 ways you can deploy an ASP.NET Core app to GCP](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/10/4-ways-you-can-deploy-an-ASP.NET-Core-app-to-GCP.html). 
You are encouraged to open this issue in the [public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/), so Developers may take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a case of an API not being enabled. Sadly the extension doesn't, yet, check that all necessary APIs are enabled before attempting a deployment.

If you go to the `APIs & Services > Library` tabbing in Cloud Console website you should be able to check if the `Google Cloud Container Builder` API is enabled and enable it if it is not.

Typically what happens is that the extension attempts to build the container that way. There should not be a hang however.